# Metro Bundler runs every time in new window

Tags: react-native

I moved my react-native project to another Mac and now I can't run it and can't find any solution to this. Now build succeeds when I run `react-native run-ios` but it always opens new window to start Metro Bundler.

I already run Metro Bundler with `react-native start` and it stays up fine with messages: `Metro Bundler ready.` and `Loading dependency graph, done.`.

But each time I run `react-native run-ios` it opens new window to start Metro Bundler even though one is already running. Result is red screen with message `No bundle URL present.`

This happens even if I close my Metro Bundler which I run with `react-native start` and only do `react-native run-ios`, where it runs it's own bundler successfully.

Any ideas why I have this behaviour?

I already tried removing node_modules, npm install, remove ios/build, run ios again, etc.

Answer (score 4):

So I had this issue and after a ton of digging, I realized that for some reason, my new Mac's `/etc/hosts` file was empty. React Native on iOS (as well as the script that starts the bundler when running `run-ios` or `run-android`) looks for the bundler at `localhost:8081`, not `127.0.0.1:8081`, but the loopback wasn't working since the file wasn't there. Point being, I created `/etc/hosts/` and added these lines:

```
127.0.0.1            localhost
::1                  localhost
255.255.255.255      broadcasthost
```

Really you only need the first line, but usually the hosts file has those three so I put them all in there in case anything else was getting confused.

Comment: Thanks, that was it for me!

Answer (score -2):

You need to clear the build folder in the ios directory and then re run the project:

1. `cd iOS`
2. `rm -r build`
3. `cd ..`
4. `react-native run-ios`

The code will run smoothly.